# Low power, cost effective way to measure CO2 (or equivalent CO2)?

Tags: sensor, low-power

I'm trying to develop a system that will monitor long term CO2 levels indoors and will run on a battery.

A lot of the conventional CO2 sensors are really power hungry and expensive. However, I came across this (http://www.ccmoss.com/gas-sensors) which claims it can measure 'equivalent CO2' in the environment where the main source of VOCs is from humans.

This seems great with a power consumption of <1mW, but it's £5.96 per sensor which is quite pricey!

Has anyone heard of anything similar, or have an idea of how 'equivalent CO2' is calculated so I could maybe use a cheaper VOC sensor and do the calculation myself?

Answer (score 5):

£5.96 ($7.74 USD) is actually incredibly cheap for a C02 sensor. I used a [Futurelec C02](http://www.futurlec.com/Gas_Sensors.shtml) sensor in a project, and it runs $34.90 with no processing capabilities at all - just a simple voltage output.

You'll have to read the datasheet for your specific device to see what "equivalent C02" means.

[Here is a PDF from Gas Sensing Solutions](https://www.gassensing.co.uk/media/1065/co2voc.pdf), a UK-based sensor manufacturer, and they say:

> Some manufacturers of air
>   quality sensors are now providing an
>   output in "CO2 equivalent units." This
>   measure is considered misleading and
>   may confuse many new to the indoor air
>   quality industry.
>
> There is currently no recognized procedure
>   to directly quantify the output of
>   these sensors to carbon dioxide or the
>   differential between inside and outside
>   concentrations that is used to determine
>   ventilation rate.

...so read the manufacturer's documentation carefully to fully understand what you're actually measuring.

I'm going to deviate from objectivity for a moment and give you an opinion: I'm skeptical of the devices you linked to. I have trouble believing they can deliver a high level of accuracy for that price, given that bare sensors alone (as you noted) are significantly more expensive. The fact that they provide a dubious "C02 equivalent" measurement rather than an absolute value makes me question their usefulness. I would want to learn a lot more about how they work and *exactly* what information they're providing before I purchased one. I'm sure someone with more experience working with air quality measurements could provide good use cases for these, but I can't help but be wary of them.

Answer (score 0):

Not much as answer but just as **experimentation** with **cheap things**,

you could try measuring resistance or conductance of **water** in presence of air, since CO2 react with water and give H+ and CO3-- , that conduct electricity... as well, this CO2 can come back to air also.

---

You could also try to **increase surface-area** of water, such as with glass-wool or capillary tubes etc,

as well you may require amplification of electronic signal. You may apply on that water,

instead DC, an oscillating voltage or a low-voltage AC could be tried ((keeping in mind all- possible hazards of AC-source, for all-sorts of reader)), to get larger and much-linear relationship of voltage and current, and better conduction in certain voltage limit than DC.

---

Effect of temperature would count in this.